# How to force a crash or delete an android application?

Tags: android, reset, android-launcher

I have created an android app and now I cannot close it from my device.

I have set the app as default launcher and I have disabled the status bar(so I cannot access the settings menu). When I press the back and home buttons nothing changes because the app runs as a launcher.

Now I want to exit from the app and change the default launcher but I cannot.

Also my device is Viewsonic vsd224 (android KitKat 4.4 system)(all in one, it is not a tablet) and it does not reset to its factory settings from any combination of buttons when it is turned off.

I want to delete or crash the app or even reset my device but I cannot find a way.

Have you any ideas what I can do?(I cannot use android studio or any other IDE).

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin I would do something like this:

```
fun crashMyApp(){
throw RuntimeException("Crash my app!")
}
```

And call this method wherever you want to force the crash to happen.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081595/how-to-force-to-crash-firebasecrashlytics) my inspiration for this answer.