# how to force to crash firebasecrashlytics?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-crash-reporting

I am developing news app and  I am new to firebase Crashlytics I want to force to crash and I want to get a report of the crash but I am not getting any crash reports how can I achieve that

below my Implementation

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener { v ->

                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()

                val intent = Intent(v.context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(urlKey, articleList[position].url)

                v.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
```

below my firebase crashlytics console screenshot
[my firebasecrashlytics console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVMQ5.png)

I want to know where I am making mistake how can I force to crash my app

Comment: did you follow the documentation to implement crashlytics ?

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial? What you are asking is literally the second step of the getting started guide, here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#force_a_crash_to_test_your_implementation

Answer (score 6):

> how can I force to crash my app

Just throw an exception that gets handled by crashlytics unhandled exception handler, e.g.

```
throw RuntimeException("crash testing")
```

Comment: Wherever you want to have your crash. For example a click listener of a "crash me" button.

Comment: but now I have implemented databinding in adapter class in the example they have tested when user clicks button but there is not button in my adapter class

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener { v ->
       val intent = Intent(v.context, DetailActivity::class.java)
       intent.putExtra(urlKey, articleList[articleList.size].url) // you can throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

       v.context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

or

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener { v ->
         throw RuntimeException("Test Crash") // Force a crash
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but firebase not detecting crashes

Comment: Did you complete to [implement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)?

Comment: it is not detected

Comment: Abi nasilsin benda turk erur

Comment: Selam Edgar, Adım adım dokümanı takip etmelisin. Başaralı bir şekilde kurulumu yaparsan, hata raporlarını görebilirsin. (Hi Edgar, you should follow the docs. step by step. If you successfully complete to implement, you can see the crash reports)

Comment: I followed documentation I have done exactly what said there but it is not showing nothing

Comment: Could you share Firebase Console -> Crashlytics  screen-shot

Comment: Hi I have added screenshot to post please check it

Comment: You didn't complete to add the sdk. If you added the sdk, uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: I have checked by filtering firebase there is showing that firebase crashlytics installed in android studio I forced crashed as you told me but crashlytics console showing nothign

Comment: It may take some time. I edited my answer. You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this inside the onCreate function:

in Kotlin: `throw RuntimeException("Test Crash")`

in Java: `throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash");`

Answer (score 0):

What about simply calling

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Exception("My test exception"))
```